# Remove compiler warnings when using F# on .NET core

Tags: f#, .net-core

When I build using .NET core (`dotnet build`) I get the following kinds of warning:

> warning NU1701: Package 'FSharpx.Async 1.13.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

However, the package *does* actually work correctly with my project.

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: Follow this issue: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Async/issues/42

Comment: @Foole So this needs to be fixed package by package?

Comment: Yeah, your options are: wait for the project to release a netstandard version, make your own custom netstandard version, switch your project to .net framework or ignore the warning

Comment: That project hasn't had a check-in for about 11 months. Seems like it isn't maintained.